# How to detect if the current value is the lowest RSI value from past

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to basically detect the extreme bottoms and Tops for the RSI. Here is what i tried for getting the extreme bottoms

```
hb = lowestbars(rsiSlow,5)  
currentLowestRSI = rsiSlow[abs(hb)] < rsiSlow ? true : false
```

Getting the lowestbars of the previous 5 bars and checking if that value of RSI is lowest. But this doesn't get me the extreme bottom of the RSI. How do i go about achieving this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First calculate the current rsi. Then use it as a source to `ta.lowest()` function.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")
current_rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)
lowest_rsi = ta.lowest(current_rsi, 5)
currentLowestRSI = lowest_rsi < current_rsi 
plot(lowest_rsi)
```